# How I shift me website from WordPress managed to linux hosting?

Tags: migration

I am now hosting my website on GoDaddy managed hosting (basic plan). Here the hosting provider company did not allow me to install third party plugins like cache plugins, etc. There are other limitations too.

Now I want to shift my website to Linux hosting. Please help me to backup my website because it automatically backs ups under GoDaddy basic plan.

Comment: do you have a ftp access and cpanel?

Comment: GoDaddy managed hosting doesn't give any access to cpanel, instead they give me their own 'managed system' access via login to godaddy account.

Comment: how about ftp? in that admin dashboard, do you see any option for backup/ databases or phpmyadmin? share a screenshot if possible

Comment: Here is link to dashboard offer in GoDaddy managed WordPress hosting https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsthehost.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F01%2Fgodaddy-managed-wordpress-panel-1024x936.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatsthehost.com%2Freviews%2Fgodaddy-managed-wordpress-reviews%2F&tbnid=iITydZXsPT3TIM&vet=1&docid=8BQwhp8h1pGIIM&w=1024&h=936&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim

Comment: I can clearly see there's a backup option. what happens when you click on that?\

Comment: It backup on GoDaddy own server. They did not give me an option to download the backup files from their own servers. They limit me to host my website only on Godaddy, not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a plugin like Duplicator to download a copy of your website and database. Then you could set up a new clean WordPress install on the new server and import your Duplicator-export.

That way you are able to test everything before canceling the GoDaddy-plan.

[Duplicator Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)